Can't "Reject and edit" Python tag wiki suggestion, because it's already too long. "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 32763."
I was reviewing a suggested edit on the Python tag wiki and I chose "Reject and edit", but when I try to submit my changes, I'm getting this error: Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 32763. How did it get that long in the first place if it can't be submitted when it's that long?
The help center says a tag wiki can be "30,000+" characters, so why is this error happening in the first place?  I guess it's a bug and the "suggested edit" interface is using the question/answer character limit of 30k. That or the help center is outdated and the tag wiki character limit has been brought down to 30k.

The current character count of the tag wiki is 33665 based on trying a different edit.
I had tried removing some outdated info before taking the screenshot, but quit when I realized how much work it would be.
Research
I looked at this question on MSE about a bug with the character count, but I'm not sure if it's related: Why is the character limit message trying to trick me?
See also: Redesigned Tags Page - Jeff Atwood's blog post introducing the "30,000+" limit

P.S. I can add specifics about the edit I wanted to make, if that would help.

sounds similar to this: About Me is too long

Maybe you can edit out 20000 characters. Does a tag wiki really need a history lesson?

@President *3665.

@President I agree, but figuring out what to remove is a lot of work. Personally I'd love to cut down the list of libraries and shorten their descriptions, but I don't have the patience right now.

Related: "Tag wikis are incorrectly limited to 30,000 characters when editing them from the revision history"

This is a bug or misfeature.
The issue here appears to be that the endpoint used for "Reject and edit", /posts/<postID>/edit-submit/<revision GUID>, is a generic endpoint that's used for all posts (tag wikis are a type of post). In the backend, this endpoint validates against the generic 30,000 character limit for posts. It will return a response indicating an error when you try to submit an edit with more than 30,000 characters of Markdown:
{
    "success":false,
    "errors":{
        "Body":[
            "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 33485."
        ]
    },
    "warnings":{},
    "source":{}
}

When directly editing a tag wiki and tag excerpt, the endpoint /edit-tag-wiki/submit/<tagID> is used. It does not have the 30,000 character limit for the Markdown. An edit with the current 32,934 character Markdown will succeed. [The length is different from above, because I have already edited to remove the course with a dead link.]
Workaround
Reject the edit. Once the edit is actually rejected (i.e., after a second person also rejects the edit), edit the tag wiki.

Thanks! The course link wasn't actually dead, it just moved (or maybe it was incorrect). I tried to edit an old revision to fix it and I found out that that has the same problem! I got the same error, "Body is limited to 30000 characters".

Maybe it'd be best to drop the limit to 30k. I mean, the Python tag wiki really doesn't need to be that long. But then adding new stuff would require removing old stuff first, hmm...

@wjandrea Yes, because you were trying to edit an old revision, which I'd expect would use the /posts/<postID>/edit-submit/<revision GUID> endpoint, as that's the endpoint for editing a specific revision.

@wjandrea While I think the Python tag wiki is quite long, and probably could be shortened substantially, it can still be edited and extended from its current size. You just can't edit a specific revision or "Reject and edit" (which edits a specific revision).

This is where the tag editing kind of falters. It is easy to add new things, it "feels" low impact. But to remove existing content, that's a destructive action and to make thar decision as an individual can be a mind job. But it is so important that it is done. To properly do that you'd probably need to organize some kind of event in chat to do it collaboratively.

@Gimby maybe we need something where we, as a community can edit and maintain Documentation. That would be a great feature. Hard to monetize ...

@rene it's the internal wiki problem. It becomes a huge mess nobody wants to look at if nobody is directly responsible for making sure it does not become a huge mess that nobody wants to look at. I have yet to see a Confluence environment where the left menu wasn't filled with complete randomness targeting at least 10 different disciplines at once :)
